# Using values in 3 columns, create a new column that takes values from one of the 3

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns `candle`,`point` and `time`. If the  candle in `candle` gets to the point,`b`,create a new column that contains the time at which candle got to the point

I tried doing this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'candle':[23,22,25,23,22,23,25,25,22],'point':['a','a','a','b','b','c','b','c','a'],'time':['2019-07-05 12:22:22','2019-07-10 12:22:22','2019-07-15 12:22:22','2019-07-20 12:22:22','2019-07-25 12:22:22','2019-07-30 12:22:22','2019-07-35 12:22:22','2019-07-40 12:22:22','2019-07-45 12:22:22']})

df                                                                      
Out[5]: 
candle  point     time             
0  23  a  2019-07-05 12:22:22     
1  22  a  2019-07-10 12:22:22    
2  25  a  2019-07-15 12:22:22    
3  23  b  2019-07-20 12:22:22    
4  22  b  2019-07-25 12:22:22    
5  23  c  2019-07-30 12:22:22    
6  25  b  2019-07-35 12:22:22    
7  25  c  2019-07-40 12:22:22 
8  22  a  2019-07-45 12:22:22 



def arrival_dates(df,end):
    candle_at_target = df[df["point"] == end]
    df = df.merge(cars_at_target,how='left',on="candle")
    return df

end_point = 'b'
```

The problem is, I don't know how to continue from here

Output Expected

```
candle  point     time             passed_time
0  23  a  2019-07-05 12:22:22    2019-07-20 12:22:22 
1  22  a  2019-07-10 12:22:22    2019-07-25 12:22:22
2  25  a  2019-07-15 12:22:22    2019-07-35 12:22:22
3  23  b  2019-07-20 12:22:22    2019-07-20 12:22:22
4  22  b  2019-07-25 12:22:22    2019-07-25 12:22:22
5  23  c  2019-07-30 12:22:22    2019-07-20 12:22:22
6  25  b  2019-07-35 12:22:22    2019-07-35 12:22:22
7  25  c  2019-07-40 12:22:22    2019-07-35 12:22:22
8  22  a  2019-07-45 12:22:22    2019-07-25 12:22:22
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'candle':[23,22,25,23,22,23,25,25,22],'point':['a','a','a','b','b','c','b','c','a'],'time':['2019-07-05 12:22:22','2019-07-10 12:22:22','2019-07-15 12:22:22','2019-07-20 12:22:22','2019-07-25 12:22:22','2019-07-30 12:22:22','2019-07-35 12:22:22','2019-07-40 12:22:22','2019-07-45 12:22:22']})


times = df[df.point=='b'].set_index('candle').time
df['passed_time'] = df.candle.map(times)
```

`map` is a very useful function when you want to broadcast a value for a whole group!

*What happened?*

Let's decompose the `times` variable:

`df[df.point=='b']` takes all the rows in which the `point` column takes value `b`

`.set_index('candle')`: we set the column `candle` as index for later use with map

`.time`: We're interested in the `time` column when `point` is `b`.

So now we have a `times` Series where each value is the time in which each candle takes value `b` and the index of said Series is the candle name.

Then comes `map`: in this case we're applying the function to the `candle` column and we're giving it the `times` Series (but better think of it as a `dict` where the keys is the index and the values are the Series values).

What `map` does is that it looks into this `times` Series and it fills the new `passed_time` column looking to make matches between the `candle` column and the `times` index, whenever there's a match the column gets filled with `times` values.

That's why the `set_index('candle')` step was key: else your `times`Series would have the original index and there would be no matches between the `candle` column and the `times` Series.

Output:

```
    A  B                    C          passed_time
0  23  a  2019-07-05 12:22:22  2019-07-20 12:22:22
1  22  a  2019-07-10 12:22:22  2019-07-25 12:22:22
2  25  a  2019-07-15 12:22:22  2019-07-35 12:22:22
3  23  b  2019-07-20 12:22:22  2019-07-20 12:22:22
4  22  b  2019-07-25 12:22:22  2019-07-25 12:22:22
5  23  c  2019-07-30 12:22:22  2019-07-20 12:22:22
6  25  b  2019-07-35 12:22:22  2019-07-35 12:22:22
7  25  c  2019-07-40 12:22:22  2019-07-35 12:22:22
8  22  a  2019-07-45 12:22:22  2019-07-25 12:22:22
```

Comment: Can you please explain the process briefly?

Comment: Edited. Please tell me if there's still some confusion

Comment: this is so elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
df=df.sort_values('candle').reset_index(drop=True)
df['passed_time']=df.loc[df['point'].eq('b'),'time'].repeat(df.groupby('candle').size()).reset_index(drop=True)


   candle point                 time          passed_time
0      22     a  2019-07-10 12:22:22  2019-07-25 12:22:22
1      22     b  2019-07-25 12:22:22  2019-07-25 12:22:22
2      22     a  2019-07-45 12:22:22  2019-07-25 12:22:22
3      23     a  2019-07-05 12:22:22  2019-07-20 12:22:22
4      23     b  2019-07-20 12:22:22  2019-07-20 12:22:22
5      23     c  2019-07-30 12:22:22  2019-07-20 12:22:22
6      25     a  2019-07-15 12:22:22  2019-07-35 12:22:22
7      25     b  2019-07-35 12:22:22  2019-07-35 12:22:22
8      25     c  2019-07-40 12:22:22  2019-07-35 12:22:22
```

Comment: This is very neat as well. Can you please explain?